# Is there a way to more efficiently code this range?

Tags: r

Hi I have a file that was imported into r,
I would like to recode one of the columns which looks like

```
Number of People
1 to 3
4 to 6 
7 to 10
.
.
.
.
```

I have a total of over 30 levels for the column 'Number of People'.
What I'd like to do is to convert them into numeric values (i.e. "1 to 3" becomes "2" and "4 to 6" becomes "5")

As I have a huge set of data to work with, is there a more efficient way to recode this or is it only possible if I use recode()?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `7 to 10` become - the average (8.5)?

Comment: You have not included anywhere in the post that you want the mean of two numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Number_of_ppl = c("1 to 3", "40 to 45")
)
```

To get what you want you need to first extract all numbers, convert to type numeric, and compute the mean:

```
library(stringr)
sapply(lapply(str_extract_all(df$Number_of_ppl, "\\d+"), as.numeric), mean)
[1]  2.0 42.5
```

If you want to have the means as a new column in your dataframe, store the result as new variable:

```
df$Number_of_ppl_mean <- sapply(lapply(str_extract_all(df$Number_of_ppl, "\\d+"), as.numeric), mean)
```

which gives you:

```
df
  Number_of_ppl Number_of_ppl_mean
1        1 to 3                2.0
2      40 to 45               42.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` based solution with the same basic structure as Chris Ruehlemann's answer

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(Number_of_People = c("1 to 3",
                                       "4 to 6",
                                       "7 to 10"))

df %>%
  mutate(first_numb = as.numeric(str_extract(Number_of_People, "^\\d{1,}")),
         second_numb = as.numeric(str_extract(Number_of_People, "\\d{1,}$"))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(avg = mean(c(first_numb, second_numb)))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Number_of_People first_numb second_numb   avg
  <fct>                 <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 1 to 3                    1           3   2  
2 4 to 6                    4           6   5  
3 7 to 10                   7          10   8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `separate` to split the column into two, and then get the `mean` of the columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
     separate(Number_of_People, into = c("first", "second"), sep="\\s*to\\s*",
           convert = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>% 
     mutate(avg =  (first + second)/2)
#  Number_of_People first second avg
#1           1 to 3     1      3 2.0
#2           4 to 6     4      6 5.0
#3          7 to 10     7     10 8.5
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Number_of_People = c("1 to 3",
                                       "4 to 6",
                                       "7 to 10"))
```